# Angular: manually destroy lazy loading module

Tags: angular, iframe, navigation, single-page-application

I have a parent app which hosts an Angular app via iframe. This parent app has multiple modules and each module has a page on its own. The problem is when I navigate to another module of the parent app, the lazy loaded module of the Angular app in the iframe isn't destroyed.

Are there any ways that I can destroy a lazy loaded module from the `app.component.ts` ?

Comment: The parent app is an Angular app as well? When you say "hosts an Angular app via iframe" is what is presented in the iframe a completely independent app or simply a lazy loaded module of the parent Angular app?

Comment: Unfortunately the patent app is built in GWT so they are completely independent apps. The parent app has a page with an iframe and the Angular app is embedded inside that iframe. They communicate with each other via postmessage.

Comment: That may be a good thing. Have you looked at any of the experimental stuff the Angular team has going on in the Angular Core api? Check out `PlatformRef` and the `destroy()` method https://angular.io/api/core/PlatformRef

Comment: I found a workaround for my case that I redirect to an empty route which will trigger ngOnDestroy. I think that's the simplest way even though it looks a bit tricky